# Approximation using $1-x \le e^{-x}$

Tags: inequality

Suppose I want to approximate a number $p_k = (1-\frac{1}{365}) \cdot ... \cdot (1-\frac{k-1}{365})$. $k$ is a natural number.

The book I'm reading says it can be done using the fact that $1-x \le e^{-x}$.

Then we got:

$$\Large p_k \le e^{-\frac{1}{365}}\cdot ... \cdot e^{-\frac{k-1}{365}} = e^{-\frac{1+2+...+(k-1)}{365}} = e^{-\frac{k(k-1)}{730}}$$

The question is - why? It follows from the assumption that if we have numbers $a_1< b_1$ and $a_2 <b_2$, then $a_1 a_2 < b_1 b_2$. It only works if they are all positive - $-2 < 3$ and $-3 < 1$ but $6>1$.

In this case, should we add the restriction that $k$ is less or equal to 365? Otherwise, some of the terms below could be negative and the inequality wouldn't work.
$p_k = (1-\frac{1}{365}) \cdot ... \cdot (1-\frac{k-1}{365})$

Comment: I'm guessing this is a problem about the probability that $k$ people have distinct birthdays. In this case, it's obvious that $k\leq365$. If $k>365$, two people must have the same birthday, and the probability becomes $0$. In this case, the product becomes:

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{365}\right)\left(1-\frac{2}{365}\right)\dots \left(1-\frac{365}{365}\right)\dots\left(1-\frac{k-1}{365}\right)=0$$

Answer (score 2):

Needless, because from $k=365$ on, $p_k=0$, so the inequality remains true.